# Java program logic needs to be explained

Tags: java, loops, logic

My book has a program similar to [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Partition.java.html).

```
public class Partition { 

public static void partition(int n) {
    partition(n, n, "");
}
public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
    if (n == 0) {
        StdOut.println(prefix);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
        partition(n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    partition(N);
}

}
```

Is there another way of writing that for loop in different way that isn't so complicated to understand for me? Thanks!

Comment: What do you think a method call `Math.min` does? Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: You're allowing yourself to be intimidated by the unknown. But you "know" what this method does probably, and if not you can surely find out, Exchanging that single call with the code it executes isn't going to make this any easier to understand I don't think.

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

When trying to understand recursive methods/functions I find it is helpful to add some wise debugging code that tells you whats going on each step of the way.  For added visual appeal I add a debugIndent that visually tells me the level that I'm at.

```
StdOut(debugIndent + "n = " + n + ", max = " + max + ", prefix = \"" prefix + "\"");
```

Put that at the start of your second partition like so:

```
Public class Partition { 

    public static void partition(int n) {
        partition("", n, n, "");
    }
    public static void partition(String debugIndent, int n, int max, String prefix) {
        StdOut(debugIndent + "n = " + n + ", max = " + max + ", prefix = \"" prefix + "\""); // TODO remove debugging code

        if (n == 0) {
            StdOut.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
            partition(debugIndent + "  ", n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        partition(N);
    }
}
```

Run that and look at what it shows you.